# C# - SNMP over TCP

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

Group,

Does anyone know anything about [SNMP over TCP](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=3430) coded in C#.  I'm just looking for some good online examples or references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question asked on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/5f56afe2-9770-47ca-81b7-3f5a93f8c2e5) is probably relevant to your interests.  There is a simple example of implementation code [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/SimpleSNMP.htm), but it obviously doesn't scale too well.  If you're looking for a library, [this small SNMP library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SNMPDLL.aspx) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks  Travis, I've taken a look at this example before...but I'm not quite sure if this method can be used for TCP. In the example they are using Socket "ProtocolType.Udp". But, what i'm looking for is Socket "ProtocolType.Tcp"...and not sure how that will work. SNMP is a connectionless protocol that uses UDP...but for my purpose I need to use SNMP over TCP/IP